# OS X - php - mkdir() - wrong chmod

Tags: php, macos, chmod, mkdir

I'm trying to create a folder using php on os x

for exemple:

```
mkdir('test','0644',true);
```

and ls -l returns:

```
d-w----r--  2 ant  staff  68 16 nov 11:27 test
```

an other

```
mkdir('test','0777',true);
```

and ls -l returns:

```
dr----x--x  2 ant  staff  68 16 nov 11:33 test
```

I don't understand why I didn't have the corrects rights on the folder
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The second parameter is supposed to be an integer, not a string.

Comment: `'0644'` and `0644` are quite different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mkdir()` uses `$mode` as an integer.
read: https://www.php.net/mkdir